# How do I create/manage subdomains on my CentoOS nameserver with httpd to reach local running webserver from outside via SSL?

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, ssl

I would need some kind of workflow for my setup I took over from someone else. Lets name the headless server "example.com".

named, dovecot, postfix, selinux and firewall-cmd are in place. I would like to use subdomains, like "webservice1.example.com" to use mainly web services via remote on this machine. Atm there is only port 80/443 open with an correct SSL cert in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is very vague, but the items you need to consider are:

- Create the subdomain on the DNS server - You are using `named` (Bind9?) so I guess you are self hosting your DNS.  This means creating the subdomain is done by adding it to your [zone file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file).  If you're not self hosting then you will need to create the appropriate `A` and `AAAA` and / or `CNAME` records with your DNS provider.
- Obtain an SSL certificate for the sub domain.  This usually requires you to make a new private key and then purchase a certificate from a [CA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority).  It is possible to get multi domain certificates which may be cheaper than multiple certificates.  Alternatively you can pay more for a wildcard certificate which implicitly will work with any subdomain.
- Configure the respective service to use the new subdomain.  At minimum the service needs to be configured to use the new certificate and private key.  But also:

  - Web servers need to be configured with an updated [virtual host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html).
  - Mail servers (postfix) may need to be configured with an updated `helo` and `ehlo` response.  I believe this is controlled with [`myhostname`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#myhostname)
  - Other services (dovecot) may be agnostic to their hostname meaning that as long as the subdomain points to the correct IP address, the service should just work.

Comment: I created the subdomain successfully. The SSL certificate runs as well. The vhost entry works. I reloaded sudo /bin/systemctl reload httpd dovecot postfix. I will fix the firewall soon. Thank you!